# Java find DateFormat of a String

Tags: java, date-format

I am having Date in string say, "2014-10-09T06:33:50.765Z".

I would like to know DateFormat of it?

Do we have any API to find out the same or we just have to go with trial & error ??

Comment: [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the API and yes, you're probably going to have to figure it out by trial and error.

Comment: No, there's no API for a computer to figure out meaning of data passed by on it's own. This is what protocols for.

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly impossible to guess date format in you case is it 10th of September or 9th of October?

But you dont need to "trial & error" There is good documentation on this topic [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)